# How do I pass a Boolean value between classes and get the desired Output

Tags: java, boolean

I am having two class 
Hello.java

```
class Hello 
{
   private boolean check  ;

public Hello()
{

}

void display()
{
      if(check == true)
      {          
      System.out.println("Available");
      }
      else if(check == false)
      {
          System.out.println("Not Availabe");
      }
}
}
```

And Main.java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean check;
                 System.out.println("Is Available(yes/no):");
                String av = sc.nextLine();
                if(av.equals("yes"))
                {
                    check = true;
                }
                else if(av.equals("no"))
                {
                    check = false;
                }

                Hello hello=new Hello();
                hello.display();
            }
    }
```

I want if i input "yes" then get the "Available" as output simmilarly with when input "no" then get "Not Available". But the value must pass through the Hello Class to get output.
But i am getting "Not Available" as output every time. How can solve it??

Comment: remove c++ and c tag

Answer (score 0):

Pass check value in constructor of Hello

```
class Hello 
{
   //check in Hello class 
   private boolean check;   //#1
     //constructor will take check as input
    public Hello(boolean check)
    {
         this.check = check
    }

    void display()
    {
          if(check)
          {          
          System.out.println("Available");
          }
          else
          {
              System.out.println("Not Availabe");
          }
    }
}
```

Now create object of Hello class with boolean value.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //this check is different from Hello class check
        //check in Main class
        boolean check;  //#2
        System.out.println("Is Available(yes/no):");
        String av = sc.nextLine();
        if(av.equals("yes"))
        {
            check = true;
        }
        else if(av.equals("no"))
        {
            check = false;
        }

        Hello hello=new Hello(check);
        hello.display();
    }
}
```

You have two check variables (see comment in code #1 and #2). Both has nothing to do with each other, both are different. #1 is instance variable of class Hello and #2 is local variable of main method.

Comment: You should avoid comparing a boolean to true or false; just use "if (check)' or if(!check)'

Comment: I just copy pasted from question.My focus was on passing boolean value in Hello class object. Updated now